How do I deter people from pressing the wrong doorbell?
I live in an apartment building with a doctor's office at the bottom floor. The doctors office has a very big button for it's doorbell next to a column of three normal sized buttons for three of the apartments. The bottom one of the three normal buttons is my doorbell.
People visiting the doctor's office regularly press my doorbell button on accident, because something about the design of the doorbells makes them think they need to press the button next to the bell for the doctor's office. Usually right afterwards, they press the correct button, which I can tell because whenever I rush to the door in case someone actually meant to ring my doorbell, I can hear the frontdoor close, which means the doctor's office must have let them in.
I have decided to turn this into a UX study, but I am unsure how to communicate clearly to people that my doorbell is likely not the one the want to press.
My main problem is, do I want to draw positive attention to the correct doorbell, or do I want to draw negative attention to mine?
An argument against positive attention is, that there is already a big sign that tells people where to press, yet they still do it wrong, while an argument against negative attention would be that I just confuse people even further. I also thought about drawing negative attention to my doorbell and then immediately redirect people more subtly towards the correct doorbell. These are my three ideas:
Positive attention:

Negative attention:

Both:


Your name is third on the list on the right-hand side (the least likely to be accidentally pushed), which makes me wonder if people are just pushing all the buttons to see who answers. If it were me, I'd disable my doorbell and make people text me if they wanted something...

@Izquierdo I disagree that it's the least likely -- as OP noted, it's right beside "Doctor's office", making it possible to misinterpret the left panel as labels and the right panel as buttons. Of course, it could still be people randomly pressing all of them :)

I noticed that after I posted my comment and came back - glad it wasn't an Answer. This could definitely be a case of fat-fingering bumping the wrong button, and that might not be fixable with a note or a sign.

 "Wet towels go here" / "Priority Queue", "Economy" / "Walk in", "Reservations" 
I can imagine many situations using the Positive attention method like your solution one.
I would go with that first and see if it is solving the problem. Just make sure your sticker is in a bright green color to draw enough attention, so that the current issue does not repeat.
Additionally I feel like it gives the following benefit too:

The visitor feels more welcomed than scaring them by saying "don't do xyz..". Its just nicer imo.


I am more in favor of positive attention.
I think the problem lies in the reading direction, from left to right, from top to bottom. If a person sees the text box on the left, the logical thing to do is to click on the button at the bottom right.

It is quite difficult to reverse this tendency. If we think of the box in the image as an open magazine, the finger to turn the page will go directly to the bottom right corner instinctively.
I would not hesitate to use any graphic resource, even the most heavy, to reverse this direction once the information has been read.

A resource that graphic designers use to divert attention to a certain point is an eye-catching image, which can even make the invitation to press the right bell more friendly:

Doctor cartoon from gettyimages.com

This is a brilliant idea, thank you! I put up the positive attention sticker yesterday but will try this next week to compare the two

Your observations/concerns are accurate and neither too subtle positive nor negative attention will probably give a 100% change of the situation.
Danielillo already pointed out that the "reading direction" is the problem. The proposed solutions with a really fat arrow or an eye catching comic figure might work like a charm!
Pictograms generally take precedence over text, but also need to convey "what to do". A "stop" sign (negative cue) will make hesitant but it actually does not imply a graphical indication what should be stopped and what else to do. Your proposal still needs to make the user read the text.
Your positive cue is more appealing than the negative cue though and a bright color hopefully draws enough attention to it. It is below the door bell knob though and relies mostly on text but the arrows do help and the fat "DOCTORS OFFICE" is a good choice for concise wording. So it could either be ignored or read first/last which will then hopefully change the user's decision.
The only way I can see is to make the grouping more prominent. For example like this:
+------Doctor-----+  +-----Private----+
|  Dr Doctor &    |  | [ Name1      ] |
|    Dr Doctwor   |  | [ Name2      ] |
|  [ Door Bell ]  |  | [ Name3      ] |
+-----------------+  +----------------+

This will create a different visual cue to the user. Vertical lines will act as a "border" increasing the separation of the two "option fields" to chose from.
Maybe a simple strip of black tape in between the doorbell signs (ideally a little longer than the height of the two fields to really form a "barrier") can already do the trick or at least give some ease to the situation.

I think part of the problem is the labeling choice to put a functional title on one button that looks like just part of a generic sign next to specific people in a stack of what are more clearly specific-person buttons.
It looks like the sign is there explaining the buttons to the right are for specific doctors, those are clearly buttons for specific people and the big icon and whatnot doesn't immediately look like it should also contain a button.
Put the office icon and title on the sign, put a stack of buttons with individual doctors' names next to it, even if they all ring the same office, then farther to the right put the individual apartments, that seems clearest.

Absolutely -- I agree that the problem is mistaking a functional element for a label for a different functional element.

I also agree, the doctor's office's button isn't clearly recognizable as a button, it confused me as well when I moved in. I can't change it though, unfortunately
